# Where is the documentation for Datacash's DataCashConf file?

Tags: xml, datacash

The Datacash payment provider uses a configuration file called `DataCashConf.xml` and I am having trouble finding the documentation for this.

The file looks like this (I have added comments myself)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Configuration>
    <!-- Indicates the server to point at (test or live) -->
    <host>https://mars.transaction.datacash.com/Transaction</host>

    <!-- Transaction timeout value in milliseconds -->
    <timeout>500</timeout>

    <!-- Log file location -->
    <logfile>c:\Program Files\DataCash\DataCash_log.txt</logfile>

    <!-- ??? -->
    <logging>5</logging>
</Configuration>
```

I want to turn off logging (I'm going to log everything myself, but 123-Reg won't let me log to their servers C drive), and am assuming I change the value for logging from 5 to something else to do this, but I don't know what to and I can't find any documentation on this files format.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Is this for the .Net API or one of the others?

Answer (score 0):

Would this be useful https://datacash.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/213 ?